# Find the percentage of occupied space of each object in a bag, where each object has a different value (unknown value, read more)

Tags: algorithms, percentages

I don't know if there is an answer for this question, but I developed a smartphone application and my competitor do something that for me is not possibile.. so here's the question:

I have a bag and inside there are X objects.

Each object occupies a certain space in the bag.

I don't know how much space each object, but I know that the order in which they are inserted, it should be according to the space occupied.

**the objects always take 100% of the space in the bag. For example if there are 4 objects, maybe the first take 43%, the second 25%, the third 20% and the last 12%**

**It is possible to know the percentage of occupied space of each object, knowing the number of objects in the bag?**

thanks everybody

(if there is something that is not clear, tell me and I'll try to explain better)

Comment: Does X has a range ?

Comment: @cgiovanardi no.. there isn't a range.. i don't think there is an answer to this question but I would like to be sure, hearing the opinion of someone else

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the point of your question, but consider that for each integer $n$, there is an object that takes $n$% of the bag (but you don't know that). You can have two objects in a bag of several way that gives you different results. For example if you have objects 1 and 2, only 3% of your bag will be used, but if you have objects 49 and 50, your bag will be at 99% full. But it still appears as 2 objects in your bag in both cases. Did I get something wrong ?

Comment: @H.Potter thanks for your answer, the objects in the bag always take 100% of the space in your bag. For example if there are 4 objects, maybe the first take 43%, the second 25%, the third 20% and the last 12%..

Comment: Then it's still impossible to know, there are several ways of having two objects in your bag: one that takes 1% and the other 99% or one that takes 49% and the other 51%. Maybe there is some hidden information that you can use to find the different values of the objects ?

Comment: @H.Potter yes this is the point! hidden info? unfortunately no .. so my competitors pretends to be able to do this thing ..

Comment: Then there is no way to know. If there are $n$ objects in your bag, you have to know at least $n-1$ of your objects to have perfect information. Your competitors are either liars or they have some more constraints on the size of the objects :)

Comment: @H.Potter ok thanks for your answer ... as I imagined.. :-/ ok if you want to answer i'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given this information, it's not possible. Let's say you have $n$ objects, then you would need at least $n-1$ constraints to have perfect information.